# How to make <select> element with my own arrow down icon?

Tags: html, css, select, css-selectors

I'd like to have my own arrow icon on the right side of select element in all browsers. I was trying to use pseudo element `:after` but it doesn't work.

```css
select {
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  &:after {
    content: 'f175';
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0px;
    right: 13px;
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="" size="1">
    <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
    <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
    <option value="High">High</option>
    <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use image like below

```css
select {
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 120px;
  background: transparent url("http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/cc_mono_icon_set/blacks/16x16/br_down.png") no-repeat right center;
}
```

```html
<select name="" size="1">
  <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
  <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
  <option value="High">High</option>
  <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```css
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill='black' height='24' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='24' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><path d='M7 10l5 5 5-5z'/><path d='M0 0h24v24H0z' fill='none'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: 100%;
  background-position-y: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<select name="" size="1">
  <option value="wybierz z listy">wybierz z listy</option>
  <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
  <option value="High">High</option>
  <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove below styles from your css and it will work

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
```